# mysql insert query, trouble with auto-increment field

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO faq (order, heading, content)
VALUES ('$_POST[order]','$_POST[heading]','$_POST[content]')
```

I have a field before it called ID that I set to auto increment and INT

I get this error "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, heading, content) VALUES ('Order','Title','content')' at line 1"

Is there something I am missing, it works just fine if the ID field doesn't exist?

Comment: Have you taken measures against SQL injections?

Comment: Please, before you do **anything** else, read up on [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/). You cannot write this kind of code. Ever. You should use a modern interface like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) which supports placeholder values and prepared statements to make this sort of thing effortless to do. If you're using `mysql_query`, it is deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP.

Comment: I am using mysqli_query

Comment: Then you should be using [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) in order to compose your queries correctly. `$_POST` should never, ever be inside your query string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

order is a sql keyword. You need to use backticks to escape the word order

```
INSERT INTO faq (`order`, `heading`, `content`)
VALUES ('$_POST[order]','$_POST[heading]','$_POST[content]')
```

Also you should escape those $_POST parameters instead of inserting them directly into your SQL query:

```
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order']);
...
INSERT INTO faq (`order`, `heading`, `content`)
VALUES ('$order','$heading','$content')
```

Comment: So I did that code
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order']);
$heading = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heading']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);

$sql="INSERT INTO faq (`order`, `heading`, `content`)
VALUES ('$order','$heading','$content')";

but it is insert empty fields into the table

Comment: What does your query string evaluate to before you run it?

Comment: I checked, and the variables are not being set to anything. I echoed them and they don't display anything

Comment: Maybe they're not in `$_POST`, as maybe you're not submitting your form via `the `POST` method.